# Sort hash elements in-place within an array

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array. Some elements are hashes. I want to sort the hashes in-place and leave the array elements in order.

Can I improve this code?

```
def sort(args)
  args.map! do |arg|
    arg.is_a?(Hash) ? arg.sort : arg
  end
end
```

For example:

```
sort [{"b"=>"2", "a"=>"1"}, "x"]
=> [{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}, "x"]
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIU your question is *how to sort a hash inplace*, since you don’t need any modifications to original array but those. To sort a `Hash` inplace you might use:

```
hash.keys.sort.each { |k| hash[k] = hash.delete k }
```

Putting it all together:

```
def sort args
  args.each { |el|
    el.keys.sort.each {|k|
      el[k] = el.delete k
    } if Hash === el
  }
end

res = sort [{"b"=>"2", "a"=>"1"}, "x"]
puts res 
# ⇒ [{"a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"}, "x"]
```

Hope it helps.